# Using parameter to adjust WHERE clause resulting in NULL evaluation

Tags: parameters, null, case, where-clause

I am attempting to use a parameter passed by an application to determine the WHERE clause in a query.  Based on the value in the parameter, it will determine the WHERE.  2 of the 3 WHERE options result in an evaluation of NULL.  The 3 potential WHERE statements are below and each work when applied independently.

```
WHERE sSC.Description IS NOT NULL
WHERE sSC.Description IS NULL
WHERE sSC.Description = @Signature
```

I attempted to execute this multiple variants but all have incorrect syntax.  Here is the most recent.

```
DECLARE @Signature AS VARCHAR (max)
SET @Signature = 'XXXPARAMETER1XXX'

Select * 
FROM Operations.dbo.sSignatureClassification AS sSC
WHERE 
    CASE @Signature
        WHEN 'Without' THEN (sSC.Description IS NOT NULL)
        WHEN 'With' THEN (sSC.Description IS NULL)
        ELSE (sSC.Description = @Signature)
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WHERE you need condition, in your case, I suggest to use simple OR:

```
DECLARE @Signature AS VARCHAR (max)
SET @Signature = 'XXXPARAMETER1XXX'

Select * 
FROM Operations.dbo.sSignatureClassification AS sSC
WHERE 
(@Signature= 'Without' AND sSC.Description IS NOT NULL) OR
(@Signature= 'With' AND sSC.Description IS NULL) OR
(@Signature<> 'Without' AND @Signature<> 'With' AND sSC.Description = @Signature)
```

Comment: Thank you, this met the immediate need.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
WHERE (@Signature = 'Without' AND sSC.Description IS NOT NULL)
OR (@Signature = 'With' AND sSC.Description IS NULL)
OR (@Signature <> 'Without' AND @Signature<>'With' AND sSC.Description = @Signature)
```

However, you should consider separating out the queries as you may find that it performs sub-optimally if the query plan is cached.

If this is in a stored procedure you should break it out like this:

```
DECLARE @Signature AS VARCHAR (max)
SET @Signature = 'XXXPARAMETER1XXX'

IF (@Signature = 'With')
   SELECT *
   FROM Operations.dbo.sSignatureClassification AS sSC
   WHERE sSC.Description IS NULL
ELSE
  IF (@Signature = 'Without')
    Select * 
    FROM Operations.dbo.sSignatureClassification AS sSC
    WHERE sSC.Description IS NOT NULL
  ELSE
    Select * 
    FROM Operations.dbo.sSignatureClassification AS sSC
    sSC.Description = @Signature
```

This will cause SQL server to generate 3 separate query plans, likely the first two will use an index scan (looking for null/not null), while the last will use an index seek.  Actually the first might use an index seek as well.  Check SQL Profiler to make sure.

Comment: Any chance you can expand on this?  I tried to find a PM option but could not.  Thank you.

Comment: Expand on separating out the queries? or the problem with query plan caching?  The problem with query plan caching is that it will make a plan for the query based on the parameters you give it FIRST, and then it will reuse that plan even if you give it different parameters, which will result in some bad query performance.